# how can I solve the MySql error "Pool is closed" in node-red

Tags: mysql, node-red

While working on a node-red flow, I needed to connect to a mysql database. The database connected for few seconds then i got the error "Pool is closed".
After searching for it, I found that it meant that the amount of connections exceeded the max allowed consuctive connection.
Any way to fix that? maybe a way to increase the maximum?

Comment: You will need to supply a LOT more information in the question. [Edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/76364043/edit) to include details of which of the many MySQL nodes you are using and how you've configured it. Also details about the database would be useful e.g. is it one you control?